# ActionScript: can Tweener scale upwards instead of downwards?

Tags: actionscript, scale, tweener

I'm using the ActionScript Tweener from [here](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/)

I have a scaling animation on one of my images but I can't seem to get it to scale (enlarge) upwards instead of downwards

```
Tweener.addTween(myImage,
{
  scaleX: 1.5;
  scaleY: 1.5;
  transition: "linear";
}
```

I have tried modifying my flex component holding the image, but the animation seems to ignore the dimensions of the image container. Any way I can do this using Tweener but without any other external components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Changed the container to a HGroup and set VerticalAlign to center

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="bottom">
  <s:Graphic mouseOver="enlargeImg(event)" mouseOut="shrinkImg(event)" ../>
  <s:Graphic ../>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: You know you can accept your own answer and get a little bit of reputation and a badge in the process?